# How can I eliminate moisture dripping from my ceilings?

Tags: humidity

I have a 30 yr old bungalow.  Last year we replaced every door and window in our house to make it more energy efficient.  Our main heating source is an air-tight wood fireplace which runs all day every day.  Our back up heat source is electric radiant in the ceilings which we keep around 12°C to keep our electric bill down.  We have no furnace or duct work in our house.  We are having problems with moisture forming and dripping from our ceilings on colder winter days.  How can we fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have any insulation in the attic space above your ceilings?

Comment: Yes, we have R20 value.

Comment: Do you have a bathroom exhaust fan, and a range hood exhaust fan?

Comment: R20 isn't really sufficient in the attic space - R40+ is I think what you usually want to target.

Comment: Ceiling insulation requirements depend on location and climate. R40 is vast overkill if the interior/exterior temperature differential is never more than say 30 degrees.

Answer (score 5):

The most likley cause of the moisture is too much humidity.

Some solutions:

- A dehumidifier
- Fans to vent/move air around (to outside)
- Increased Insulation in the attic (to avoid a large temperature difference between the ceiling and the attic)

Basically the humidity needs to be lowered inside the house.

You can get a Hygrometer to measure the humidity to see where it is at.  If it is above 60% then its definately a bit humid.